# REST services running on Glassfish

Tags: web-services, rest, netbeans, glassfish, war

I've developed REST web services using Jersey with **NetBeans IDE**. 
Now I want to provide those services on **Glassfish 3.1**, without using NetBeans.

I want something like the .aar file that is created when we build web services with Apache Axis2.

Can you tell me how to do it? I have to use the .WAR file, right?

It is something like: http://qallme.sourceforge.net/docs/sec_DeployingAWebService.html ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it by following that tutorial that I've mentioned above.
At first that was not working because of the `context-root`on glassfish-web.xml. I had not filled it with the root resource.